# Where are the other ASCII control characters?

Tags: ascii

It seems that we only use '\0'(null),'\a'(bell),'\b'(backspace),'\t'(horizontal tab),'\n'(line fee),'\r'(carriage return),'\v'(vertical tab),'\e'(escape).

Where are the other ASCII control characters?Whats the usage of other ASCII contorl characters?Do they still act as control command of printer?

thanks.

Comment: http://sankofa.loc.edu/savur/web/Memory_files/image001.gif

You get everything there.

Comment: @David Brunelle: Please post that as an answer so we can upvote it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were designed for control of terminals really, not just printers. It was pretty common back in the day on 80x24 character terminals to need to hit Ctrl-S (0x13 or XOFF) to pause output and Ctrl-Q (0x11 or XON) to unpause it again. Ctrl-G (0x07 or BEL) make the terminal beep. I suppose that could have worked on a printer too, but it would have to have been a *really* loud beep to be heard over those old chain printers.

Ctrl-S, Q, and G still work on most shells. The Windows shell doesn't do anything with G, but S and Q work.

CR and LF are of course still used in terminals, although they don't do quite what you'd expect from their printer definitions. On most OSes LF is used to terminate lines. Some old Macs just use CR, and Windows likes to use both.

Answer (score 7):

They are all [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters).

Comment: I like it how all the +1 and -1 votes fight for the final value of my answer :)

Comment: actually,the wiki page *does not* answer my question.it says the contorl characters was *orginally* for device control.so what about now?i could not get the answer.

Comment: What they mean depends on the device.  In many cases most of them now do nothing, but in others they might do something weird and unrelated to their name.